# cómo formatear un billon en javascript ? ej: $4,782,330,000 => 4.78 B

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Ayuda porfa, cómo  formatear un billon en javascript ? ej: $4,782,330,000 => 4.78 B   alguna libreria ya pobre esto:

```
var f = d3.format("0.2s");

document.write(
  f(1e9).replace(/G/,"B")
);
```

pero me imprime 4 B quisiera que me imprima 4.78 B, dos decimales

Gracias

Answer (score 8):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente función:

```js
function abbreviateNumber(value) {
  let newValue = value; //Asignamos el valor que llega a la función en una variable

  const suffixes = ["", "K", "M", "B","T"]; //establecemos un array de sufijos, 
//los cuales representan: Menor que Mil (""), Miles (K), Millones (M), Billones (B) y Trillones (T)

  let suffixNum = 0; //Se declara suffixNum para establecer la posición del Array

//El siguiente While nos dice "Mientras el valor es mayor o igual a 1000" entonces divídelo entre mil
//y suma uno a "suffixNum" (así va estableciendo la posición del array)
  while (newValue >= 1000) { 
    newValue /= 1000;
    suffixNum++;
  }

//A nuestro valor le especificamos una "precisión de 3", lo que hace es que redondeada a una precision de dígitos significativos.
  newValue = newValue.toPrecision(3);

//Por último concatenamos el sufijo establecido anteriormente
  newValue += suffixes[suffixNum];
  return newValue;
}

console.log(abbreviateNumber(4782330000));
```

También te muestra los "Miles", "Millones" y "Trillones". Espero te ayude.

Comment: podrías explicar un poco que hace tu código , para que mejores la calidad de la respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Coloqué algunos comentarios para hacerlo un poco más claro, no se si me dí a explicar correctamente, pero creo que puede ser de ayuda. Saludos.